# What is this theme by Vivaldi called?

Tags: classical-music, guitar

What is this piece by Vivaldi called? It's Exercise 97 in Noad's "Solo Guitar Playing 1" book, with no explanation other than "Theme by Vivaldi".

You can hear a recording here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Oqnf3R-JNo

[image: Vivaldi Noad exercise 97]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This melody appears (in 12/8 time) as the sixth movement of [Vivaldi's *Gloria* (RV 589)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_(Vivaldi)#RV_589), an aria for soprano on the text *Domine Deus, rex coelestis.*